# RichText box has not displaying the large text in WPF with MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

How to display the large text in the richtextbox. I need to use with MVVM pattern.
Can anyone suggest me a wpf control to display large text or how to make the richtextbox to display entire content?

Comment: what do you mean by large text? is it font size? are you trying to inject xaml? or you just text to be scaled?

Comment: No.. I mean I need to display the info messages from sql in the WPF screen. The messages are more than 1000 lines. My richtextbox display only 100 lines

Comment: you can use textbox and set AcceptReturn="true". like this   <TextBox Height="66" Margin="563,46,265,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"/>

Comment: textbox can display more than 1000 lines? Is there any Controls for display like a Information board

Comment: textbox can display multiple lines. there will be a vertical scroll in it. but it will only contain text it will not be formatted. all text will be of same size and font

Comment: ok.. If need to format some lines in red color, how to do that formatting?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6844/discussion-between-tanya-and-shoaib-shaikh)

Comment: Try setting textbox Height and Width properties to Auto and TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"

Answer (score 0):

Richtextbox can display more than 1000 lines. I use the one for cat and it works just nice(with all the formatting and etc). May be you have vertical scroll OFF and you cant see the rest of the lines?! see  Shoaib Shaikh answer with suggested properties values.

Comment: Even i set the VerticalScrollVisibility to visible. Its not displaying the scrollbar. Since it is in MVVM i dont know how to apply such things can you give some example pls

Answer (score 0):

Rich text box can also have same properties to accept multiple lines as textbox does. in order to conditionally format some lines in red you will have to provide Flow document in RichTextbox. you can create flow document by xml. this is an article could be helpful 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/BindableWPFRichTextBox.aspx